# How to group an array of object with property with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this array:

```
var arr = [
  {
    count: 27,
    dataRil: "08/06/21",
    subCateg: "FISH",
  },
  {
    count: 22,
    dataRil: "08/06/21",
    subCateg: "DOG",
  },
  {
    count: 28,
    dataRil: "09/06/21",
    subCateg: "FISH",
  },
  {
    count: 18,
    dataRil: "09/06/21",
    subCateg: "DOG",
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    dataRil: "09/06/21",
    subCateg: "CAT",
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    dataRil: "09/06/21",
    subCateg: "BIRD",
  },
];
```

I want to group it by label and in the data element, I want the count in the array.
How can I achieve this

output like:

```
var datasets = [
  {
    label: "FISH",
    data: [27, 28],
  },
  {
    label: "DOG",
    data: [22, 18],
  },
  {
    label: "CAT",
    data: [0, 1],
  },
  {
    label: "BIRD",
    data: [0, 1],
  },
];
```

Comment: You are asking the same question again. But this doesn't help till you're not clear what exactly do you want? 
Try something own. If you get stuck then ask question?
In last time you've asked the same question I've asked about where does `0` comes from in label `CAT` and `BIRD`

Comment: indeed, the CAT/BIRD situation is not clear.

Comment: In this case, when not exists a element with a dataRil in "data" properties 
is added to 0. 
The important thing is that all arrays of the properties "data" must have the same length

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, first we want to reformat the data based on date. And also we are not sure about the subCateg, so before we reformat we we would extract all the subCateg values.

Then we can extact the data we want from the updated/reformated data.

```js
const arr = [{
    count: 27,
    dataRil: "08/06/21",
    subCateg: "FISH",
},
{
    count: 22,
    dataRil: "08/06/21",
    subCateg: "DOG",
},
{
    count: 28,
    dataRil: "09/06/21",
    subCateg: "FISH",
},
{
    count: 18,
    dataRil: "09/06/21",
    subCateg: "DOG",
},
{
    count: 1,
    dataRil: "09/06/21",
    subCateg: "CAT",
},
{
    count: 1,
    dataRil: "09/06/21",
    subCateg: "BIRD",
},
];
const dataOnDate = {};
const dataSet = [];
const subCateg = [];
function getFormatedData() {
    arr.forEach(er => {
        if (subCateg.includes(er.subCateg) === false) {
            subCateg.push(er.subCateg);
        }
        if (dataOnDate[er.dataRil] === undefined) {
            dataOnDate[er.dataRil] = {};
        }
        dataOnDate[er.dataRil][er.subCateg] = er.count;
    });
}
getFormatedData();
 

function extractData() {
    const dataSet = [];

    subCateg.forEach(cat => {
        let mid = {
            label: cat,
            data: []
        };
        Object.keys(dataOnDate).forEach(data => {
            if (dataOnDate[data][cat] !== undefined) {
                mid.data.push(dataOnDate[data][cat])
            } else {
                mid.data.push(0);
            }
        });
        dataSet.push(mid);
    });
    return dataSet;
}

const result = extractData();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If it has helped you can the answer be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd turn it into an object using a classic histogram method, then turn it back into an array...

```
var arr = [
  { count: 27, dataRil: "08/06/21", subCateg: "FISH" }, 
  { count: 22, dataRil: "08/06/21", subCateg: "DOG" }, 
  { count: 28, dataRil: "09/06/21", subCateg: "FISH" }, 
  { count: 18, dataRil: "09/06/21", subCateg: "DOG" }, 
  { count: 1, dataRil: "09/06/21", subCateg: "CAT" }, 
  { count: 1, dataRil: "09/06/21", subCateg: "BIRD" } 
]

let tempObj = {}

arr.forEach(el => {
  if (tempObj.hasOwnProperty(el.subCateg)) {
    tempObj[el.subCateg].data.push(el.count)
  } else {
    tempObj[el.subCateg] = {data: [el.count]}
  }
})

let newArr = []

let longestData = 0

//get the longest data array
Object.keys(tempObj).forEach(key => {
  if (tempObj[key].data.length > longestData) longestData = tempObj[key].data.length
})

Object.keys(tempObj).forEach(key => {
  if (tempObj[key].data.length < longestData) {
    for (let i = tempObj[key].data.length; i < longestData; i++){
      tempObj[key].data.unshift(0)
    }
  }
})


Object.keys(tempObj).forEach(key => newArr.push({"label": key, "data": tempObj[key].data}))

console.log(newArr)
```

[Working Pen](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1011)

EDIT: Added code to populate shorter arrays

Comment: Thanks,
it is a good way but for the properties "data" of BIRD and CAT it is [1] and not [0,1]

Comment: I've amended the code, so now it populates the data arrays with 0's until they are all as long as the longest natural data array.

Comment: Yes, exactly I have to build a histogram. but if I add a new element {count: 5, dataRil: "10/06/21", subCateg: "FISH"}, I expected [{
  data: [27, 28, 5],
  label: "FISH"
}, {
  data: [22, 18, 0],
  label: "DOG"
}, {
  data: [0, 1, 0],
  label: "CAT"
}, {
  data: [0, 1, 0],
  label: "BIRD"
}] but I have: [{
  data: [27, 28, 5],
  label: "FISH"
}, {
  data: [0, 22, 18],
  label: "DOG"
}, {
  data: [0, 0, 1],
  label: "CAT"
}, {
  data: [0, 0, 1],
  label: "BIRD"
}]

Comment: I think you need to look at the logic and think about how it should work in practice, then ask the question again. I can't see how you could logically get an output like that.

Comment: Sorry, actually I wasn't very clear ... As you said I have to build a histogram, so in labels: ["08/06/21", "09/06/21", "10/06/21"], and in the dataSet [{
  date: [27, 28, 5],
  label: "FISH"
}, {
  date: [22, 18, 0],
  label: "DOG"
}, {
  date: [0, 1, 0],
  label: "CAT"
}, {
  date: [0, 1, 0],
  label: "BIRD"
}].
Starting from the initial array

Comment: But why would the data arrays be arranged in that way? From line 24 tempObj creates the histogram, so you can carry on from there if you like. I can't see any logical reason the data arrays would output as you've described.

Comment: Because I use chart js and the data is expected that way. Anyway thank you, I can edit what you posted to me. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This might work if you don't want 0 in the data for the element. I don't know what 0 is in your case but this might work

**EDIT**: The logic has been updated. I think you are trying to prefill elements you have remaining in front with 0. The current solution will fill the array of remaining length with 0 at the front.

```js
    var initialArray = [{ count: 27, dataRil: "08/06/21", subCateg: "FISH" }, { count: 22, dataRil: "08/06/21", subCateg: "DOG" }, { count: 28, dataRil: "09/06/21", subCateg: "FISH" }, { count: 18, dataRil: "09/06/21", subCateg: "DOG" }, { count: 1, dataRil: "09/06/21", subCateg: "CAT" }, { count: 1, dataRil: "09/06/21", subCateg: "BIRD" } ];

    var arr = initialArray.reduce((accum,curr) => {
         if(accum[curr.subCateg] == undefined) {
           accum[curr.subCateg] =  {
              label: curr.subCateg,
              data : [curr.count] 
           };
           return accum;
         }
          let count = accum[curr.subCateg]['data'];
          count.push(curr.count);
          return accum;
        
    },{});

    var arr = Object.values(arr);
    var maxLength = arr.map(x => x.data.length).reduce((max, val) => max > val ? max : val);

    var result = arr.map((data) => {
      if(data.data.length < maxLength){
          let newarr = (new Array(maxLength - data.data.length));
          data.data = [ ...newarr.fill(0) , ...data.data];
      }
      
      return data;
    });
    console.log(initialArray);
    console.log("Result" , result);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a good way but for the properties "data" of BIRD and CAT it is [1] and not [0,1]

Comment: @Michele see now does it satisfy your need?